# Create necessary counts of Lists in the run time

Tags: c#

I'am new in C#. I wrote this code:

```
List<List<Transaction>> transactionsLists = new List<List<Transaction>>();

foreach(var cur in _currencyRate.GetCurrencies())
{
    transactionsLists.Add(_transaction.GetTransactionList(cur.CurrencyName, dateStart, dateEnd, "", quantity));
}
int currencyID = _currencyRate.GetCurrencyIDByName(currency);
List<CurrencyRate> rates = _currencyRate.GetRates(currencyID, dateStart, dateEnd, quantity).ToList();            
List<Transaction> transactionsUSD = new List<Transaction>();
List<Transaction> transactionsBYR = new List<Transaction>();
transactionsBYR = transactionsLists[0];
transactionsUSD = transactionsLists[1];
```

Of course, It's work fine. But I wanna to generate lists in runtime. So, I wanna to get counts of elements of `_currencyRate.GetCurrencies()` (this is just a list) and generate the count of lists, that has type `< Transaction>`. And copy all elements to a new lists. Is there is any way in C# how I can do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you meant by *I wanna to generate lists in runtime* ?

Comment: Are you asking about the [List<T>.Count property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Are you looking for `IDictionary<Currency, IList<Transaction>>`?

Comment: For example, I have 2 elements in _currencyRate.GetCurrencies(). I need to get 2 lists. If I have 3 elements - 3 lists. etc...

Comment: You've already got them in the list of lists?

Comment: Yop. I have list, which consists of two lists.

Comment: @Alexander perhaps `_currencyRate.GetCurrencies().Select(d => d.Count()).ToList()` would help you achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var transactionsDict = new Dictionary<int, <List<Transaction>>>();        
    foreach(var cur in _currencyRate.GetCurrencies())
    {
        transactionsDict[cur.ID] = _transaction.GetTransactionList(cur.CurrencyName, dateStart, dateEnd, "", quantity)
    }
```

then you can call to transactionsDict by currency key, and it will return your List
for exammple:

```
var transaction = transactionsDict[22];
```

but it will return error if this not found, so i recommend use:

```
List<Transaction> transactionList = null;
if (transactionsDict.TryGetValue(yourID, out transactionList))
```

if that key found it rerurn true and you transactionList

Answer (score 0):

"So, I wanna to get counts of elements of `_currencyRate.GetCurrencies()` (this is just a list)..."

This can be done with `_currencyRate.GetCurrencies().Count`.

"...and generate the count of lists, that has type `<Transaction>`."  (My example uses `long` instead of `Transaction`, but I think this will give you what you appear to be asking about.)

```
        List<List<long>> testList = new List<List<long>>();
        int myCounter = 0;

        // Populate your list here.

        foreach (var listOfLong in testList)
        {
            if (listOfLong.Count > 0)
            {
                // This looks like what you were asking about, but this IF statement is unnecessary, since all members of the list must be longs.
                if (listOfLong[0].GetType() == typeof(long))
                {
                    myCounter++;
                }
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("count = " + myCounter.ToString());
```

"And copy all elements to a new lists."

```
List<List<long>> testListCopy = new List<List<long>>(testList.ToArray());
```